# Remove columns of dataframe based on column names of itself and following columns in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe consisting of 271 columns. Each column is named as "sampleName_time".

```
 [1] "A01_0"  "A01_24" "A01_48" "A01_72" "A02_48" "A03_0"  "A03_24" "A03_48" "A04_24" "A04_48" "A05_0"  "A05_24" "A05_48"
 [14] "A05_72" "A06_0"  "A06_48" "A07_0"  "A07_24" "A07_48" "A08_0"  "A08_24" "A08_48" "A08_72" "A09_24" "A09_48" "A09_72"
 [27] "A10_0"  "A10_24" "A10_48" "A11_0"  "A11_48" "A11_72" "A12_48" "B01_0"  "B01_24" "B01_48" "B01_72" "B02_24" "B02_48"
...
```

The *time* can be 0, 24, 48 or 72.
I want to keep the columns that refer to the same sample and have measurements on all time points (0, 24, 48 and 72).
For example, The sample *A01* is ok because we have columns "A01_0", "A01_24", "A01_48" and "A01_72". *A02* is not ok because there is only one column named "A02_48" but no others. *A03* is not ok too. But *A05* is ok.
So for the above example, the pruned dataframe I want would be as follows

```
"A01_0"  "A01_24" "A01_48" "A01_72" "A05_0"  "A05_24" "A05_48"
"A05_72" "A08_0"  "A08_24" "A08_48" "A08_72" "B01_0"  "B01_24" "B01_48" "B01_72" 
...
```

The following is my approach. But it seems so complicated as I need to have the nested if statements and maybe I need to use next to skip some iterations of the for loop.

```
for (i in seq_along(colnames(exprs))){
  if (tr_split(colnames(exprs)[i], "_")[1][2] == 0){
    if (tr_split(colnames(exprs)[i+1], "_")[1][2] == 24){
      # not complete with more if statements
    }
  }
}
```

Are there some neat ways to do that?
I think there may be some neat way using `sapply(colnames(exprs),function(x){ someFunction})`
Thanks

Comment: Provide example reproducible data: `dput(colnames(exprs))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this mock data set that reproduces your column names.

```r
df <- data.frame(replicate(8, 1:10))
colnames(df) <- c("A01_0", "A01_24", "A01_48", "A01_72", "A02_48", "A03_0",
                  "A03_24", "A03_48")

#    A01_0 A01_24 A01_48 A01_72 A02_48 A03_0 A03_24 A03_48
# 1      1      1      1      1      1     1      1      1
# 2      2      2      2      2      2     2      2      2
# 3      3      3      3      3      3     3      3      3
# 4      4      4      4      4      4     4      4      4
# 5      5      5      5      5      5     5      5      5
# 6      6      6      6      6      6     6      6      6
# 7      7      7      7      7      7     7      7      7
# 8      8      8      8      8      8     8      8      8
# 9      9      9      9      9      9     9      9      9
# 10    10     10     10     10     10    10     10     10
```

What you can do is keep only groups of columns where you have 4 different values (0, 24, 48, 72):

```r
library(dplyr)
un <- data.frame(col = colnames(df)) %>% 
  group_by(gp = substr(col, 1, 3)) %>% 
  filter(n() == 4) %>% 
  pull(gp) %>% 
  unique()

# In this case, we have
un
#[1] "A01"
```

Then, use that vector get columns that starts_with/contains one of the values in `un`:

```r
df %>% 
  select(starts_with(un))

#    A01_0 A01_24 A01_48 A01_72
# 1      1      1      1      1
# 2      2      2      2      2
# 3      3      3      3      3
# 4      4      4      4      4
# 5      5      5      5      5
# 6      6      6      6      6
# 7      7      7      7      7
# 8      8      8      8      8
# 9      9      9      9      9
# 10    10     10     10     10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
df <- data.frame(A01_0 = 1,
                 A01_24 = 2,
                 A01_48 = 3,
                 A02_48 = 1, 
                 A05_0 = 1,
                 A05_24 = 1)

df

A01_0 A01_24 A01_48 A02_48 A05_0 A05_24
1     1      2      3      1     1      1

df[substr(names(df), 1, 3) %in% names(which(table(gsub('_\\d+', '', names(df)) ) > 1))]
  A01_0 A01_24 A01_48 A05_0 A05_24
1     1      2      3     1      1
```

Breaking down the steps:

```
gsub('_\\d+', '', names(df))
[1] "A01" "A01" "A01" "A02" "A05" "A05"
names(table(gsub('_\\d+', '', names(df)) ) > 1)
[1] "A01" "A02" "A05"
which(table(gsub('_\\d+', '', names(df)) ) > 1)
A01 A05 
  1   3 
names(which(table(gsub('_\\d+', '', names(df)) ) > 1))
[1] "A01" "A05"
```